# 'for in' stops working after raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, if-statement, raw-input

I am creating a program where the hero saves two hostages in 10 seconds. The first things he needs to do is decide who to save first, then type the code for bomb to rescue the hostage, if the user types the name of the hostage wrong he can type it again. But after I type wrong once the loops stops or after i finnished saving the first hostage the loop stops.

This is the code:

```
holly = True
molly = True

for i in range(0,11):
    print "Who will you save?"
    print "Time paste:", i

    decide = raw_input("> ")

    if decide == "Holly" and holly:
        print "You decided to save Holly."
        print "Whats the code?"
        code = random.randint(100,1000)
        print code
        decide = int(raw_input("> "))
        if decide != code:
            exit('You are dead!')
        print "You saved Holly!"
        holly = False
    elif decide == "Molly" and molly:
        print "You decided to save Molly."
        print "Whats the code?"
        code = random.randint(100,1000)
        print code
        decide = int(raw_input("> "))
        if decide != code:
            exit('You are dead!')
        print "You saved Molly!"
        molly = False
    elif not holly and not molly:
        print "You saved both of them!"
        break
    else:
        print "Try again!"
```

I am doing it all in a Class, here is the full code:

```
class Mountains(object):
    def enter(self):
        print "After you defeated Josh. You headed towards the mountains."
        print "There you're final target sits."
        print "Jim the \"Knigh\""
        print "He has 2 hostages. Holly and Molly, you have 10 seconds to save them."
        print "They are bought straped to a bomb, each one in different location"
        print "Each bomb has a 3 digit code."

        holly = True
        molly = True

        for i in range(0,11):
            print "Who will you save?"
            print "Time remaining:", i

            decide = raw_input("> ")

            if decide == "Holly" and holly:
                print "You decided to save Holly."
                print "Whats the code?"
                code = random.randint(100,1000)
                print code
                decide = int(raw_input("> "))
                if decide != code:
                    exit('You are dead!')
                print "You saved Holly!"
                holly = False
            elif decide == "Molly" and molly:
                print "You decided to save Molly."
                print "Whats the code?"
                code = random.randint(100,1000)
                print code
                decide = int(raw_input("> "))
                if decide != code:
                    exit('You are dead!')
                print "You saved Molly!"
                molly = False
            elif not holly and not molly:
                print "You saved both of them!"
                break
            else:
                print "Try again!"

            if holly and molly:
                exit("You are dead!")

            print "After you saved both, Jim comes in angry!"
            print "He takes his shotgun! And startes firing!"
            print "You take cover, and start to think where to shoot!"
            print "You only have 4 bullets! Make it count!"

            hero = 100
            villain = 100
            bullets = 4
            direction = ["up", "down", "left", "right"]

            while True:
                print "In which direction do you shoot?"
                print "Hero health:",hero
                print "Villain health:",villain
                print "Bullets left:", bullets

                if hero < 0:
                    exit("You are dead.")
                elif villain < 0:
                    exit("You win")
                elif bullets == 0:
                    exit("You are dead.")

                bullets -= 1
                shoot = random.choice(direction)
                print shoot

                choice = raw_input("> ")

                if choice == shoot:
                    print "You shoot %s, hitting Jim but he also hits you." % shoot
                    hero -= random.randint(20,30)
                    villain -= random.randint(30,50)
                elif choice != shoot:
                    print "You shoot %s, but you missed. Jim didn't miss." % shoot
                    hero -= random.randint(10,20)
                else:
                    print "Try again."
        else:
            print "Try again"
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The code does exactly what it appears to do.

Comment: The code works fine separately. But in a class it doesn't.

Comment: How are using using the code in the class? Please [edit] your answer and show that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by using continue. These are the parts that I inserted continue in:

```
if decide == "Holly" and holly:
    print "You decided to save Holly."
    print "Whats the code?"
    code = random.randint(100,1000)
    print code
    decide = int(raw_input("> "))
    if decide != code:
        exit('You are dead!')
    print "You saved Holly!"
    holly = False
    continue
elif decide == "Molly" and molly:
    print "You decided to save Molly."
    print "Whats the code?"
    code = random.randint(100,1000)
    print code
    decide = int(raw_input("> "))
    if decide != code:
        exit('You are dead!')
    print "You saved Molly!"
    molly = False
    continue
else:
    print "Try again!"
    continue
```